# ASP.NET MVC - Provide additional data to dynamically created ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selectlistitem

I have a view that allows the user to dynamically add items (In this case, "movies"). Each movie has a "Rating" that should be selectable from a drop-down list. Previously, this came from an enum, and this worked fine (This appears commented out below). However, the "Rating" list has recently been moved to a configuration file.

The code looks like so:

Create.cshmtl

```
@model MyProject.Models.ViewModels.ShelfAddViewModel

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Movie[0].Name)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Movie[0].Rating)
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="movieContainer">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Movie)
        </tbody>
        <tfoot id="item-list">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn" value="Add" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>

...

@section Scripts {
@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#btnAdd").on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Movies/AddMovie',
            success: function (partialView) {
                $('#movieContainer').html(partialView);
            }
        });
    });
```

MovieAddViewModel.cshtml

```
@model MyProject.Models.ViewModels.MovieAddViewModel
<tr>
    <td>
        <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />
    </td>   
    <td>
        <select asp-for="Rating" asp-items="Model.RatingList" class="form-control"></select>      
@*<select asp-for="Rating" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<RatingType>()" class="form-control"></select>*@
    </td>     
    <td>
        <input type="button" onclick="Remove(this)" id="removeMovie_@Model.Uid" class="btn" value="Remove" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

MovieController.cs

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AddMovie([Bind("Id,Movie")] ShelfAddViewModel shelf)
    {
        shelf.Movies.Add(new MovieAddViewModel());
        return PartialView("_Movie", shelf);
    }
```

MovieAddViewModel.cs

```
public class MovieAddViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Movie Title")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Rating")]
    public string Rating { get; set; }
    // public RatingType Rating { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> RatingList { get; set; }    


}
```

The new list of ratings comes from a JSON file and is loaded like so:

```
        var standards =
            _configuration.GetSection("Standards");
        var movieStandards = standards.GetSection("MovieStandards").Get<List<string>>();
        var movieStandardSelectList = movieStandards.Select(x=> new SelectListItem() { Text = x, Value = x }).ToList();
```

My question is, how do I get this List onto the ViewModel? I can't add it to the constructor as ASP doesn't know how to dynamically create objects unless the constructor has no parameters. I can't just update the RatingList property when I create the ViewModel, as this disappears when I add another Movie. I don't feel like I should be directly accessing the settings from my ViewModel either. What's the best approach here?

(Please note: I've modified my code to make it an easier to follow question for anyone else who has the same issue - apologies for any mistakes. Please advise if I can word my question title better)

Comment: Pls post action you use to create MovieAddViewModel.cshtml

Comment: I'm not even getting to the Create - the drop down contents disappear for any previous row when I click "Add" - only the new entry is populated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this. One of them just load it inside of the controller.

It is hard for me to understand from your answer what controllers or actions  you  are really using, so I will give you a hint , and you can adapt it to your code

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
private readonly List<SelectListItem>  _movieStandardSelectList ;

  public MyController( IConfiguration configuration)
  {
      
   var movieStandards = configuration.GetSection("Standards:MovieStandards").Get<List<string>>();
   _movieStandardSelectList = movieStandards.Select(x=> new SelectListItem() { Text = x, Value = x }).ToList();       
  }
  public ActionResut MyAction()
 {
       var model = new MovieAddViewModel
       {
       RatingList=  _movieStandardSelectList;
       .... another your code  
       }
    return View(model);
}
```

another way that I am usually using is to create a global static variable

```
public  static List<SelectListItem>  MovieStandardSelectList {get; set;};
```

and put the code that you can see in the constuctor into the startup file where   assign the list  to this global variable. But I don't put the detail code here since I am afraid that it will meet too many critics.

Comment: The first solution just doesn't work for me though. If I create a new instance of MovieAddViewModel, and inside the constructor I create the list of Standards, this works fine. However, if I create the instance in the controller, then set the property of the list (as per your example) then the list disappears when I add another Movie to the list in the front end. If I inspect the ModelState in CHrome then the RatingList element disppears from the earleir entries. 

I agree the second solution is a little poor but I may have to go with that!